# Array name as variable

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm going through K&R and it says array name is not a variable and it cannot be used in constructions like a=pa or a++.

Isn't `s` an array name here?

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    main(){
        printf("%d", strlen("test"));
    }

    int strlen(char s[])
    {
        int n;
        for (n = 0; *s!= '\0';s++) // why is s++ valid even though it is declared as an array
            n++;
        return n;
    }
```

Comment: Arrays decay to pointers when passed to a function.

Comment: You aren't even declaring `n`.

Answer (score 3):

No, in this context it's a pointer to a `char`. Your function declaration is **completely** equivalent to:

```
int strlen(char *s)
```

As you'll see, it's actually impossible to pass an array to a function: a pointer to the first element is what is actually passed.

Thus, since `s` is actually a pointer and not an array, you're free to modify it as you please.

Comment: Then why is there a restriction on modifying array names, even though char s[] is equivalent to char *s? If I write char s[10], why can't I say s++?

Comment: @ben because `char s[10]` is not decaying to a pointer because it's no a function parameter...?

Comment: I think what I'm asking is `s` is an array name, but at the same time it is a pointer to the first element of the array. So why can't I make it point to the second element? Is that a compile time check that I shouldn't do that?

Comment: Ok, what if in the case when `s` is an array name say `int s[10]`. Isn't `s` a pointer to the first element here? Should I take it as a constant pointer?

Comment: @ben It all depends on the context. For example, `s[10]` in a function declaration is exactly the same as `s[]`. Don't consider it a "constant pointer", it's not the way to go.

Comment: @cnicutar No, I'm not asking in the context of a function declaration. I'm asking about the case when `s` is a local array variable within a function.

Comment: If it's a local array variable, then you can't modify it.

Comment: @Barmar Do you know what's the rationale behind that?

Comment: Everything about arrays in C is somewhat arbitrary.  Most other types are first-class -- you can assign them and they copy the entire value.  Arrays automatically decay to pointers when used in a value context, but they decided to treat them as names in variable declarations, for consistency with other types.

Comment: @ben: there's some stuff about it in http://cm.bell-labs.com/who/dmr/chist.html. Basically it's because C arrays evolved from a previous construct in which the name of the array *actually was* a pointer, and the array itself was a separate chunk of memory from the variable that referred to it.

Comment: @cnicutar: Yep, that one essay gives the long answer to most questions about C rationale for which the short answer is "historical reasons" :-)

Answer (score 3):

From the [horse's mouth](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> #### 6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators
>
> ...
> 3 Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or the
> unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has
> type ‘‘array of *type*’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to *type*’’ that points
> to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object has
> `register` storage class, the behavior is undeﬁned.

The expression `"test"` is a string literal, which has type "5-element array of `char`".  When you pass `"test"` as a parameter of `strlen`, by the rule above, what actually gets passed is a pointer whose value is the address of the first character in `"test"`.

Which brings us to...

> #### 6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes)
>
> ...
> 7 A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of *type*’’ shall be adjusted to ‘‘qualiﬁed pointer to
> *type*’’, where the type qualiﬁers (if any) are those speciﬁed within the `[` and ] of the
> array type derivation. If the keyword `static` also appears within the `[` and `]` of the
> array type derivation, then for each call to the function, the value of the corresponding
> actual argument shall provide access to the ﬁrst element of an array with at least as many
> elements as speciﬁed by the size expression.

So in the prototype for `strlen`, `char s[]` is equivalent to `char *s`; `s` is declared as a pointer to `char`, not an array of `char`.

C's treatment of arrays is a bit baroque compared to other languages.  That's due in part to the BCPL and B heritage.  If you're curious as to why, you can read dmr's [The Development of the C Language](http://cm.bell-labs.com/who/dmr/chist.html) for some insights.

Comment: From the first reference, if in the above said cases "array of type" is converted to "pointer of type" then why is the statement `a++;` invalid? Where a is declared like `int a[10];`. Here, we are not using `sizeof` , `_Alignof` or `&` operator. So, shouldn't it be converted to "pointer of type"?

Comment: @hatter: The operand of the `++` and `--` operators (both prefix and postfix) must be a *modifiable lvalue* (6.5.2.4/1 and 6.5.3.1/1); however, an array expression is not a modifiable lvalue (6.3.2.1/1).  You cannot change the value of `a`, because there's no storage set aside for a variable `a` independent of the array elements themselves.

Answer (score 1):

No, acctually `s` is a pointer name.
The declaration `int strlen(char s[])` is same as `int strlen(char *s)`

Answer (score 1):

When Char s[]={...}  is declared address is attached to s, which never changes (like constant pointer) and anything try to change this property becomes an illegal operation such as s++.

But In function call *int strlen(char s[])* , array is passed as pointer.